# Testing SOQL insert operation

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, code-coverage

I have an apex class that takes a call note id, finds a related sObject record, creates and object with the ids of both, and then inserts that record into an sObject. This code works when I run it from a visualforce page or a trigger, but when I run the test class method for it, the test fails. The test works by specifying a call note id which is passed to the apex class method. The method then performs the insert operation and then back in the test method, a select statement is run along with code to determine if the records (which link call notes and records from another sObject):

```
 //test if the Call Note already has an associated record in the 
    @isTest static void testInsert(){
        object Call_Notes_To_Strategy_Rating__c
        string testCid = '12345678';
        List<string> strategy_ratings = new List<string>{'trthrth985dd','sdfgegr8432d'};
            List<string> cNoteIds = new List<string>{testCid};
        AddStrategyRating.linkCnToSr(cNoteIds,'insert');
        List<Call_Notes_To_Strategy_Rating__c> queryList = [select id,Call_Notes_Id__c,Strategy_Rating_Id__c  from Call_Notes_To_Strategy_Rating__c where Call_Notes_Id__c =: testCid];
        integer queryListSize = queryList.size();
       if(queryListSize > 0){
           for(string sr : strategy_ratings ){
               for(Call_Notes_To_Strategy_Rating__c record2 : queryList){
                    if(testCid == record2.Call_Notes_Id__c && sr == record2.Strategy_Rating_Id__c ){
                        queryListSize--;
                    }
                }
            }
           System.assertEquals(queryListSize,0);
        }else{System.assertEquals(2,0);}
    }
```

**When I run the code from this test via a visualforce page, it is successful so what could be causing the code to fail when it's run in the test class?**

Comment: How do you run a test method from a VF page?

Comment: @Girbot I wasn't actually running the test itself, just the logic in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create your own test data.

> ## [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm)
>
> Starting with Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 24.0 and later, test methods don’t have access by default to pre-existing data in the organization, such as standard objects, custom objects, and custom settings data, and can only access data that they create. However, objects that are used to manage your organization or metadata objects can still be accessed in your tests such as:
>
> - User
> - Profile
> - Organization
> - AsyncApexJob
> - CronTrigger
> - RecordType
> - ApexClass
> - ApexTrigger
> - ApexComponent
> - ApexPage